# How to enter value in dropdownlist (using AJAX) that is not visible in selenium remote webdriver by perl

Tags: ajax, perl, selenium, remotewebdriver

In selenium, I want to enter value in dropdown list.

I tried with various methods, nothing worked for me:

1. ```
   $driver->find_element("//select[\@id='expiry-date-month']/option[\@value='4']")->click();
   ```
2. ```
   my $element = $driver->find_element('expiry-date-month','id');
   my @arry= $element->find_elements->('option','value');
   foreach my $option (@arry)
   { 
       if $option->get_text() =='5';
       {
           $option.click(); 
       }
   }
   ```

I want to Select the Month check box values when I am not getting any error message, please show me a solution for this

HTML code:

```
<form id="form-credit-card" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" novalidate="novalidate">
<div class="row-fluid"/>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid card-wrap">
<div class="row-fluid name-wrap">
<div class="row-fluid dob-wrap hide" style="opacity: 0;">
<div class="row-fluid maestro-wrap hide" style="opacity: 0;">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span3 iframe expiry-wrap">
<label for="expiry-date">Expiration date</label>
<select id="expiry-date-month" class="expirydatemonth selectBox" size="1" name="expirydatemonth" style="display: none;">
<option value="">Month</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<a class="selectBox expirydatemonth selectBox-dropdown selectBox-active" style="width: 30px; display: inline-block; -moz-user-select: none;" title="" tabindex="0">
<span class="selectBox-label" style="width: 0px;">Month</span>
<span class="selectBox-arrow"/>
</a>
<span class="slash">/</span>
<select id="expiry-date-year" class="expirydateyear selectBox" size="1" name="expirydateyear" style="display: none;">
<a class="selectBox expirydateyear selectBox-dropdown" style="width: 30px; display: inline-block; -moz-user-select: none;" title="" tabindex="0">
</div>
```

Comment: try using $option->get_value() instead of $option->get_text(). lemme know if it works.

Comment: even i m using $option->get_value(); it does not worked.

Comment: my $elem1 = $driver->find_element("//select[\@id='expiry-date-month']");
      print "elem1:$elem1 \n";
      my $child = $driver->find_child_element($elem1, "./option[\@value='5']");
      print "child: $child \n";
      my $txty1=$child->get_value();
      print "txty1: $txty1 \n";    
      $child->click();                                                                                  here click operation is not performed if any other alternative is there, please help me how to select that value and enter into that dropdown

Comment: my $elem1 = $driver->find_element("expiry-date-month","id"); my $child=$driver->find_child_elements($elem1, "//option");
Please try the above and check

Comment: my $elem1 = $driver->find_element("expiry-date-month","id"); 
      print "elem1:$elem1 \n";
      my $child=$driver->find_child_elements($elem1, "//option");
      print "child:$child \n";                                               here it gives output as Selenium::Remote::WebElement=HASH(0x5c389c0)         child:ARRAY(0x9370168)

Comment: Nice...since there are multiple elements it returned array...now can u run a loop over $child and print get_value() for each element in Array.

Comment: my $elem1 = $driver->find_element("expiry-date-month","id"); print "elem1:$elem1";my $child=$driver->find_child_elements($elem1, "//option");print "child:$child";our @rts=$driver->find_child_elements->($elem1, "//option");
foreach my $option (@rts) 
{print "value";print "option:$rts[$option]";print "option:$option";my $valu1=$option->get_value();print"value: $valu1 \n";if($valu1=='5'){$option->click();}}
here i got output as "elem1:Selenium::Remote::WebElement=HASH(0x5bf9120)child:ARRAY(0x9326960)" progarm will be terminated